# PHP Datetime object outputs trailing zeroes, affects query against MySQL datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, yii2, where-clause

The following expression

```php
$datetime = new \DateTime('2016-06-02 19:30:17', new \DateTimeZone('America/Tijuana'));
$datetime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('GMT'));
```

is returning `2016-06-03 02:30:17.000000` (note that it is outputting 0's are not present in the input).

So in Yii2's query building, a query against a db datetime column like the following, cannot be made because of the trailing 0's.

```php
->andFilterWhere(['created_at' => $this->datetime->format('php:Y-m-d H:i:s')]);
```

Why is datetime object outputting 0's in the first place?

I suppose a comparison with `BETWEEN` or operands like `>=` might do, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are the microseconds which are generated by default as the default format is `Y-m-d H:i:s.u`. You can override it by specifying `Y-m-d H:i:s` if that's what you want.

Comment: You're correct but I sort of knew this already. The issue specifically was in the format parameter at `$this->datetime->format('php:Y-m-d H:i:s')]);` where I was prepending 'php:' (a framework thing with dates formating) something not necesary with the date class. Thank you very much. @phreakv6